# UILabel Rotation not working on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uilabel, cgaffinetransform

I have an IBOutlet UILabel *instructions; I would like to set it vertically with a rotation (via code) and I use this method:

```
instructions.center = CGPointMake(instructions.frame.origin.x - (instructions.frame.size.height / 2) + instructions.frame.size.height, 
                                       instructions.frame.origin.y - (instructions.frame.size.width / 2) + instructions.frame.size.height);;
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 0);
transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, -M_PI_2);    
[instructions setTransform:transform];
```

These instructions work perfectly when I use an old .xib file (Xcode 4.6) for user interface; if I use Storyboard with AutoLayout on iOS 7 and 8 (I'm updating an app), the rotation not work properly and the label is out of the view (see screenshots in the link, the same thing is for segmented controls), but on iOS 6 it works. Any ideas?

[image: Screenshots]

Comment: Just to save the knee-jerk responses: `instructions` is definitely non-`nil`?

Comment: Delete or comment out the `setTransform:` line. Run the code. Does the label appear where you expect it? In other words, let's try to determine where things are really going wrong - is it the transform, or is it the initial position?

Comment: One more thing. In Cocoa programming, as in humor, timing is everything. Tell us _where_ that code is located. Is it in `viewDidLoad`, for example? What makes it run?

Comment: I would say it's autolayout that interferes with your changes. It will undo what you did, depending on where your code is. If it's in viewDidLoad it certainly will.

Comment: Thanks for answers. Yes, `instructions` isn't nil and the code is located in `viewDidLoad`. If I comment `setTransform:` the label appears where I expect it. In the second screenshot, I use autolayout for the background ImageView and for the white view, but not for the label.

Comment: But if I Clear Constraints of all elements of the view, the rotation doesn't work anyway!

Comment: I don't understand why the rotation puts the label in the correct position in the old .xib, but in the new view puts it out of the screen